# Retrieving active user information script with ksh?

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

I’m working with an application which runs on AIX and doesn’t provide any information on which users are currently using the system. Instead it just has a utility userInfo which lists all user ID and user names in the db:

```
>userInfo <path to app> -list
   696969 Doe, John 
   123456 Doe, Jane
   121212 Jones, Mike
   232323 Sanders, Chris
   345678 Smith, Mary
```

Etc…

The way I retrieve which users are currently in the system is by first searching for active user sessions This returns a string with the user ID (number) in the following format.

```
>ps –ef | grep <app name> | grep user 
     <process name and path info…> -user 696969 <more process and path info> 
     <process name and path info…> -user 121212 <more process and path info>
```

And then running the userInfo utility with grep

```
>userInfo <path to app> -list | grep 696969
    696969 Doe, John
```

The problem with this is that it’s all manual and has to be repeated for each separate user ID that ps –ef  finds. This takes a lot of time when there are many users in the system and I’m usually asked to send an active user list on very short notice.
I would like to create a script that would automate the process. Preferably in KSH, but bash will do as well. I could run the script and it gives me a list of current users IDs and names:

```
>script.ksh 
    696969 Doe, John 
    232323 Sanders, Chris
    345678 Smith, Mary
```

I would appreciate the help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the first output to `sed 's/.*-user \([^ \t]*\).*/\1/'` and then use a for loop to grep for each userid. Good luck!

The sed command will filter the userid.

To be more specific:

```
for userid in $(ps –ef | grep <app name> | grep user | sed 's/.*-user \([^ \t]*\).*/\1/')
do
    userInfo <path to app> -list |grep $userid
done
```

A better version:

```
for userid in $(ps –ef | grep -E "$1.*user|user.*$1" | sed 's/.*-user \([^ \t]*\).*/\1/')
do
    userInfo $(which $1) -list |grep $userid
done
```

In which $1 is the name of the app passed as argument to the script, beware this is untested (or rather tested in bash).